# PyQt Compiling .qrc file with pyrcc4 for use in Maya under OSX

Tags: macos, pyqt, maya

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to compile a resource file (file name is resource.qrc). I'm using PyQt to make an user interface for Maya and I'm doing it in OSX 10.6.8. PyQt, Qt, Sip are working completely fine. I was originally using Windows and compiled my resource file under win7.

I managed to locate the pyrcc4 executable here

**/Applications/Autodesk/maya2013/Maya.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/pyrcc4**

and here

**/usr/local/bin/pyrcc4**

but when I use this executable I get the following error

```
dyld: Library not loaded: libQtCore.4.dylib
Referenced from: /Applications/Autodesk/maya2013/Maya.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/pyrcc4
Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap
```

Am I using the correct pyrcc4 executable? I couldn't find any documentation online about compiling .qrc files under OSX so I'm uncertain. If it is the correct pyrcc4, how can I rectify the issue mentioned above? Is there an alternative way to compile .qrc files under OSX?

I also located the executable rcc under **/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.1/bin/**. Compiling with rcc compiles it in C++ successfully.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pyrcc4` seems not to be able to find the Qt libraries.

Try to find the directory wihch the libraries are in and set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable to point to it:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/path/to/qt/libs"
```

or use it directly:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/path/to/qt/libs" pyrcc4 <inputs>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reponse. I've been unable to locate the libraries, at least libQtCore.4.dylib doesn't appear to exist on my machine if that's even possible.

Comment: Hi again, I was unable to locate the libraries because Qt was configured with frameworks turned on. After uninstalling and reinstalling, with Qt configured without frameworks, I'm able to successfully run pyrcc4 and compile the qrc file. cheers